# What is the difference between Eclipse "Import" and "Create project from existing source" for Android projects?

Tags: android, eclipse, import

I know there are two ways to import the existing Android projects into Eclipse. That is, "import" and "create project from existing source". But what are the differences between the two import methods? Can anyone explain in details?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I guess it´s simple:

1) Import: Import an Eclipse-Project, with preferences and everything other

2) from existing source: Import project of another IDE like IntelliJ IDEA (or no IDE project at all = only plain sources). You gotta set new preferences like Build targets etc.

Answer (score 4):

I believe "import" requires a .project file, as in you are importing a pre-existing project, while "create project from existing source" will allow you to select pre-existing source files to generate a new project.